# Kotlin WEB API MySQL r2dbc connection problem

Tags: mysql, api, kotlin, r2dbc

I just trying to do some tests with Kotlin, I'm from .NET this is new territory. I've DBeaver installed on my machine and I can connect to the remote MySQL without issues.

I generate the project from start.spring.io with the following options:
Gradle - Groovy, Sprint Boot: 3.0.0, Packaging: Jar and Java: 17

With dependencies:
Spring Web, Spring Data R2DBC and MySQL Driver

My application.properties:

```
spring.r2dbc.url=r2dbc:pool:mysql://192.168.1.2:3306/DBEmployee
spring.r2dbc.username=root
spring.r2dbc.password=password
logging.level.root=DEBUG
```

When I try to run the app I have this error:
2022-12-18T10:01:16.162Z ERROR 8340 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [io.r2dbc.spi.ConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'connectionFactory' threw exception with message: Unable to create a ConnectionFactory for 'ConnectionFactoryOptions{options={database=DBEmployee, host=192.168.1.2, driver=mysql, password=REDACTED, protocol=, port=3306, user=root}}'. Available drivers: [ pool ]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:648) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create a ConnectionFactory for 'ConnectionFactoryOptions{options={database=DBEmployee, host=192.168.1.2, driver=mysql, password=REDACTED, protocol=, port=3306, user=root}}'. Available drivers: [ pool ]
at io.r2dbc.spi.ConnectionFactories.get(ConnectionFactories.java:143) ~[r2dbc-spi-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]

This is supose to be a simple thing... Can someone help me please?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you attach `gradle.build` file? Probably you miss some dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

as Koziołek mentioned you should add the following to your gradle build file as a dependency:

```
runtimeOnly 'dev.miku:r2dbc-mysql:0.8.2.RELEASE'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similiar error, but the root cause is the scope of dependency, change to: `runtimeOnly` works.